# Writing a recursive base class concept in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

In C++, I want to restrict the template parameter `T` of class `Foo<T>` to strictly be an inheritor of `Foo<T>`. To do this, I write the following:

```
template <typename TSelf> class Foo;

template <typename TSelf>
  requires (is_base_of<Foo<TSelf>, TSelf>)
class Foo
{
};
```

The error I get is

`'Foo': requires clause is incompatible with the declaration`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You cannot. It's a non-starter, even if this error was resolved. Checking for derivability requires a completely defined object type. Thus `class A : Foo<A> ...` will always be ill-formed.

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk On an unrelated note, thanks for making those videos on PluralSight :)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks, any workaround for this? I'm guessing `static_assert` won't function either?

Comment: @M.A thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Within CRTP, derived class is incomplete.

You might add that assertion inside a method which should be called, as destructor:

```
template <typename TSelf>
class Foo
{
    // ...
    ~Foo() { static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Foo<TSelf>, TSelf>); }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: It solve the problem, but Foo and TSelf don't support `is_trivially_copyable` now.

Comment: @macomphy: You might place the `static_assert` in another method which should be called as constructors, so destructor might still be trivial.

Comment: We have a member function that `static_cast` base pointer to derived pointer and i think it is a good place to add `static_assert`. However, for the `static_cast` will abort itself without the `static_assert`, seems we have done extra things.